# Adding multiple links under same column in JSON response

Tags: javascript, html, json, datatable

I am trying to

1. capitalizeFirstLetter of each word of the title in the json response
2. and generate multiple links under the same color (Delete, edit..)

i have been trying with the below code but seems like everytime i add something the page goes blank, can you help me do that ? thanks in advance

[Js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/hnb0j6qy/4/)

i am using datatable, heres how my table looks like

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Desc</th>
      <th>Options (delete, edit)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Desc</th>
      <th>Options (delete, edit)</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

and my js function below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": [

      {
        "title": "Hey",
        "description": "hoy",
        "id": 1
      },

      {
        "title": "Hey",
        "description": "hoy",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "title": "Hey",
        "description": "hoy",
        "id": 3
      }
    ],
    "columns": [{
      "data": "title"
    },
                {
                  "data": "description"
                },
                {
                  "data": function(item) {
                    return '<a href="/delete/' + item.id + '">Delete</a>';
                  }
                }
               ]
  });

  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
    alert(data[0] + "'s salary is: " + data[5]);
  });
});
```

Comment: "everytime i add something the page goes blank"...what do you mean by add something? You mean add some more code? What code did you add? Do you get any errors in the browser console? None of the code above appears to try and do either of the two things you mentioned in the question, so it's hard to see what the issue is. The only obvious problem I can think of with your code currently is that the "Delete" button currently navigates the user to a new page, because that's what hyperlinks do. You either need to suppress its default behaviour, or maybe use a button instead.

Comment: i mean do trials with the code @ADyson

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: forget about what i tried @ADyson can u tell me how to generate multiple links under the same color (Delete, edit..)

Comment: I would thing you can just amend `return '<a href="/delete/' + item.id + '">Delete</a>'` to include more links

Comment: @ADyson thats what i meant by every trials i do, every time i try to amend a new link to it, it doesn't work. i'm sure i'm not doing it the right way. can you show me how pls ?

Comment: Something like `return '<a href="/delete/' + item.id + '">Delete</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="/edit/' + item.id + '">Edit</a>'` maybe?